# How can i set a different image for each cell of my tableview

Tags: iphone

How to set a different image for each cell of my table view. i want to do it through array of image names

Comment: Please read [FAQs](http://stackoverflow.com/faq)first.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use following code...

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

/* Initialise the cell */

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"MyTableViewCell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
}

/* Configure the cell */

NSString *cellImageName = [[self cellImageNames] objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];//cellImageNames ism image names array where 
UIImage *cellImage = [UIImage cellImageName];
[[cell imageView] setImage:cellIcon];

// Other cell configuration code...

return cell;
}
```

Hope, this will help you...

Comment: if it's help that do accept the answer not for me but other. So if they have similar problem than they can choose best solution. It's help you and stack overflow..

Answer (score 5):

for example:

```
cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"image%i.png", indexPath.row]];
```

or

```
cell.imageView.image = (UIImage *)[yourArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

Answer (score 5):

Your solution is here go to this link  [How to add UIImage in the UITableView](http://www.edumobile.org/iphone/iphone-programming-tutorials/how-to-add-uiimage-and-uilabel-in-the-uitableview/)

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView  cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
     static NSString *MyIdentifier = @"MyIdentifier";
     MyIdentifier = @"TableView";

     MainView *cell = (MainView *)[tableView  dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: MyIdentifier];
     if(cell == nil) {
          [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MainView" owner:self   options:nil];
           cell = tableCell;
        }

  [cell LabelText:[arryList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
 [cell ProductImage:[imagesList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
  return cell;
  }
```

Uitableview with image shows like

[image]

Answer (score -1):

```
cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"];
```